# How do I use an offscreen DC to render a compilation of bitmaps all at once?

Tags: c++, winapi

Here's some code:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hidden = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HBITMAP hiddenbmp = CreateBitmap(288,288,1,24,NULL);
HBITMAP hiddenold = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hidden,hiddenbmp);
HDC other = GetDC(NULL);
HDC otherhdc = CreateCompatibleDC(other);
HBITMAP sprites;
if (color)
    sprites = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_COLOR_SPRITES));
else sprites = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BLACKWHITE_SPRITES));
HBITMAP otherold = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(otherhdc, sprites);


// Find x and y coordinate for the top left of the visible screen
int x = game.Player_x, y = game.Player_y, ypos = 0;
if (x < 4)  x = 4;
if (x > 27) x = 27;
if (y < 4)  y = 4;
if (y > 27) y = 27;
if (modx == -100) modx = x; // modx and mody are initialized to -100
else x = modx;
if (mody == -100) mody = y;
else y = mody;
x -= 4;
y -= 4;

// Draw lower layer
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        if (game.Layer_Two[x + i][y + j] != 0)
        {
            int xpos = game.get_pos(game.Layer_Two[x + i][y + j], ypos, false);
            BitBlt(hidden, (i * 32), (j * 32), 32, 32, otherhdc, xpos, ypos, SRCCOPY);
        }
    }
}

// Draw upper layer
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        if ((game.Layer_Two[x + i][y + j] != 0 && game.Layer_One[x + i][y + j] >= 64 && game.Layer_One[x + i][y + j] <= 111))
        {
            int xpos = game.get_pos(game.Layer_One[x + i][y + j], ypos, true);
            TransparentBlt(hidden, (i * 32), (j * 32), 32, 32, otherhdc, xpos, ypos, 32, 32, RGB(255, 255, 255));
        } else {
            int xpos = game.get_pos(game.Layer_One[x + i][y + j], ypos, false);
            BitBlt(hidden, (i * 32), (j * 32), 32, 32, otherhdc, xpos, ypos, SRCCOPY);
        }
    }
}

    // Draw the compiled image to the main window
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
BitBlt(hdc, 32, 32, 288, 288, hidden, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

SelectObject(hidden,hiddenold);
DeleteDC(hidden);
DeleteObject(hiddenbmp);
SelectObject(other,otherold);
DeleteObject(other);
DeleteDC(otherhdc);

ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
```

This is in a function called DrawMap() which - what do you know - draws a map (consisting of 2 layers of 9 by 9, 32 by 32 pixels tiles).  What I'm trying to do is compile the 9 by 9 tiles in an offscreen (ie invisible) DC and then render it to the main window all at once so that it is impossible to see the tiles being drawn the way they actually are - left to right, top to bottom.  With this code, nothing is drawn to the main window.

Even weirder, I tried using only the 'other' hdc (not the 'hidden' one - although my intention was for the 'otherhdc' to be hidden).  I had the BitBlt() and TransparentBlt() functions on lines 35, 48 and 51 using 'otherhdc' as the source hdc and 'other' as the destination hdc.  Then 'other' was copied to 'hdc' (hWnd's DC) on line 56.  This worked exactly the way I wanted it to, EXCEPT 'other' was rendered to 0, 0 on the screen (the SCREEN, not the WINDOW - like 0, 0 on the ACTUAL, PHYSICAL SCREEN).  Weird.  Although I guess it's basically what I'm aiming for, minus having 'other' drawn.

I realize that since this will be used a lot, to maximize efficiency the destructors for the DCs and such shouldn't be called in the function, but should be instead called at the end of the application (ie only one time).  I just included them to give a better picture of the function.

Comment: You set `other` equal to `GetDC(NULL)`, which is the screen DC. That's why it's painting on the screen.

Comment: ok.  how do I make an offscreen DC?

Comment: [CreateCompatibleDC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922550.aspx) comes to mind. Don't forget to [DeleteDC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183533(v=vs.85).aspx) it when you're finished with it.

Comment: I tried using CreateCompatibleDC() and it doesn't show anything in the main window once copied in line 56.

Comment: More specifically, I used CreateCompatibleDC(NULL)

Comment: It appears you want to use an intermediate DC to render your images in their proper places, then do a final BitBlt() to the target Window from the rendering you just built. Is that a decent summary?

Comment: I tried it both with 'other' writing to 'hidden' and then 'hidden' being copied to 'hdc' and just with 'otherhdc' writing to 'other' and 'other' being copied to 'hdc'.  Neither produced anything.

Comment: Yes, couldn't have said (and didn't say) it better myself.

Comment: One more thing. Where is your BeginPaint()? (I'm assuming this is in regards to a WM_PAINT message)? and I see the PAINTSTRUCT, woefully unused, in the beginning of the code. If this isn't a WM_PAINT handler, sok. but good to know.

Comment: Oh.  huh.  Guess I'm missing that.  I think I originally had it in there.  Is it mandatory?  Up until I decided to add an intermediate renderer it was painting fine.

Comment: It isn't being called from WM_PAINT

Comment: OK. good to know. give me a minute. Someone else will likely answer ahead of me, but thats ok. so long as you get a good answer.

Comment: You should be calling `ReleaseDC` on `other`. Not releasing the screen DC after borrowing it can do some pretty weird stuff. I can't find the picture I took when one of my programs glitched because of that, but there's something about red circles on parts of explorer windows showing through other parts of explorer windows that makes you wonder.

Comment: @chris LOL been there. That was when I had "Release what you Get, Delete what you Create" tatooed on the inside of my eyelids.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I can definitely say it's a good thing I was in my computer classroom when that happened and not the library or something. They get confused enough by high contrast there, let alone glancing over to see that son of a glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!!

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969905.aspx) which gave me the right method.  I just used one an hdc which I initialized to GetDC(hWnd), which I set to transparent before drawing anything to it.  Then I set it to opaque afterwards.  Easy-peasy.

Comment: btw - this means I didn't end up using an intermediate (offscreen) DC.  In case anyone cares.

...What's that?  No one cares?

oh...ok

Comment: Note: You can *radically* improve your painting performance by maintaining a dedicated off-screen DC with the content you want rendered as needed on it, and reducing your WM_PAINT to a simple BeginPaint-BitBlt-EndPaint. Think about that for awhile and it will hopefully come to you how it works. Oh, and **important**: don't forget to `ReleaseDC()` that `GetDC(hWnd)` acquired dc when you're finished with it.

Comment: How does that increase performance?  Remember, this isn't in WM_PAINT.  It's in a function which is called whenever the game map needs to be drawn.  Either my way or the one your mentioned, the tiles will have to be drawn to a DC.  With the method you enumerated, they would then have to be copied.  With my method there is no extra copy.  They are just temporarily invisible.

Comment: The tiles *are* drawn to a DC, absolutely. But when? Anytime your window region is invalidated (any part of it) you're revamping the world both then *and* when you computationally update. There is no reason to do that. If you update to a backing-store DC when computational changes happen, then `InvalidateRect()` only the changed area of your screen, your actual render within WM_PAINT (which is the slowest part) becomes literally an afterthought, especially if you follow through on the optimizations in the article you linked.

Comment: Well I can see your logic.  And I appreciate your advice.  But actually my WM_PAINT would still be rather non-aftherthoughtish, since I have several fixed graphics which I haven't mentioned yet that I draw to hWnd which never need to be changed again.  The actual game tiles are not drawn during WM_PAINT.  They are drawn by a function which isn't even called by WM_PAINT.
When is part (or all) of the window invalidated?  I don't allow it to be maxed or sized.  And I am pausing the game whenever there is a dialog box open.

Comment: So the game tiles you said are not drawn during a WM_PAINT. They're rendered directly to the screen then? If so, what happens when any region of the visible window is invalidated? You don't allow it to be maxed or sized, so as long as you have foreground and RIT, you're probably just fine. I'm used to doing by maintaining off-screen imagery rendering in the compatible dc, then *any* rendering, WM_PAINT-induced or otherwise, is always a BitBlt-only from said dc. But if direct-rendering works for you as is, you'll probably see little benefit in your current design to retool now.